# R code to replace every cell in one column after searching a match from other

Tags: r

If there are phone number columns in two tables but not in same order. Then how can we select each phone number in Table 1, find it in Table 2 and select Age corresponding to that number and add it in new column of Table 1

```
Table_1                           Table_2    
PhNo          Name                Ph No            Age
987677632     Rajeev              986444656        24
342343255     Simon               875445555        26
986444656     Jack                987677632        23
875445555     Rahul               342343255        22
```

Comment: Try `df2$Age[match(df1$PhNo, df2$Ph No)]`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is a "left join" which can be easily done with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(Table_1, Table_2, by = c("PhNo" = "Ph No"))
```